# Questionable Normalizing

Tags: mysql, sql, database, forms, normalize

I'm new to designing DB's and MySQL

so to keep it short the information I have is `AppId, Last Name, First Name, Gender, Age, DoB, Relation, School Name, School Address, School Phone Number, Teachers, Councilers, If they are in childcare`
(AppID is the application ID being submited)

basically this is how I see everything being determined and what tables should be created to be most normalized

```
AppID -> Child ID
childID -> Last Name, FirstName, Gender, Age, DoB, Relation, School Name, Grade, Child Care
School Name -> Address School, School Phone Number, teacherID,counselorID
teacherID -> First Name, Last Name, Course
CounselorID -> First Name, Last Name, Counselor type
```

however I'm not sure if attempting to completely normalize this is a good idea since this is a rather small group I'm helping which may cause joining the tables to take longer than a regular grouped look up and may take up more space.

Another concern is MySQL only allows 1 auto incremental variable, which I could define a similar thing in a query but would rather not have to if it's possible. The 2 incremental's would be teacherID and CouncelorID

so any input would be very appreciated

Edit: here's the basic structure, also will add modifications attributes later, dropped courses for now. Thank you

```
   CREATE TABLE `Client_Child_Info` (
      `FirstName` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
      `LastName` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
      `Gender` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
      `Age` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
      `DoB` date NOT NULL,
      `Relation` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
      `Grade` varchar(3) NOT NULL default 'NA',
      `ChildCare` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
      `ChildID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`ChildID`),
      KEY `Age` (`Age`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Basic Child Information' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

    CREATE TABLE `Client_Child_Schoolinfo` (
      `SchoolID` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `SchoolName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `SchoolAddress` varchar(50) default NULL,
      `SchoolPhone` varchar(15) default NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`SchoolID`),
      KEY `SchoolName` (`SchoolName`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='School Information for a given ID ';

    CREATE TABLE `Client_child_teacher` (
      `TeacherID` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `FirstName` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
      `LastName` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
      `Guidance` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'determines if the person is a guidance councilor or teacher',
      PRIMARY KEY  (`TeacherID`),
      KEY `Guidance` (`Guidance`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Teacher information';

    CREATE TABLE `Client_RTchild` (
      `AppID` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `ChildID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`ChildID`),
      KEY `AppID` (`AppID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Reference Table Applicant to Client' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

    CREATE TABLE `Client_RTteacher` (
      `SchoolID` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `TeacherID` int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`TeacherID`),
      KEY `SchoolID` (`SchoolID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Reference Table for teacher to school ';

    CREATE TABLE `Client_RTschool` (
      `ChildID` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `SchoolID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`SchoolID`),
      KEY `ChildID` (`ChildID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Reference Table Child to SchoolID it is attending' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

ALTER TABLE `Client_Child_Info`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `Client_Child_Info_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ChildID`) REFERENCES `Client_RTchild` (`ChildID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `Client_Child_Schoolinfo`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `Client_Child_Schoolinfo_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`SchoolID`) REFERENCES `Client_RTschool` (`SchoolID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `Client_child_teacher`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `Client_child_teacher_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`TeacherID`) REFERENCES `Client_RTteacher` (`TeacherID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `Client_RTschool`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `Client_RTschool_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ChildID`) REFERENCES `Client_RTchild` (`ChildID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `Client_RTteacher`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `Client_RTteacher_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`SchoolID`) REFERENCES `Client_RTschool` (`SchoolID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: I would normalize it as much as possible.  What you have so far is not nearly enough.  For example, School Name should not be part of the Child table.  Since you are new, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: I would not worry about the space while normalizing tables

Comment: Can you post your suggested schema with `CREATE` statements, it will be easier to give you feedback.

Comment: One thing that I would suggest is adding date fields to all tables: `CreatedOn`, `UpdatedOn`, `DeletedOn` to all tables. Also if you have users in your system, then `CreatedBy` and `ModifiedBy` can be a good idea.

Comment: Also, consider a table for `courses` instead of putting it in your `teachers` table and a separate reference table to map courses taught by teachers.  Presumably, one teacher can teach more than one course and one course can be taught by different teachers.

Comment: Probably a better question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ or http://dba.stackexchange.com/...

Answer (score 0):

...An old one and the comments are heading into one direction.

Let's put some rationale to statements:

The baselining to share table like structured information is MS Excel or Office software from any other vendor. Unfortunately those client applications are not good in near-simultanous edit by multiple authors, however are good enough to distribute information from ONE author to multiple readers. So if the working mode is the second there is no use in putting any effort to transfer data and data concept to a database system since MS Excel is literally common sense and distribution/training effort is low.

However in case near-simultanous edit by multiple authors is needed and you can afford server hardware and application development a database on a server would be the best place to store data.

Ok, given the decision for a database has been taken:
To go for normalisation or denormalisation is a design decision. Factors like maintenance, setup effort and hardware support play a role for design decisions. Software function design depends on the data model design and the software function design must support the business logic which in your case is to deal with applications. Unfortunately denormalization often builds on assumptions (on top on those basic assumptions that you also have in place for a normalized model)  according to the Business Logic, that in future developments often are revised with the ugly consequence that software function must also be changed by then. Coming from there the denormalization has some benefits, if the software has not a time limited scope.